# AWS authenticate multiple apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS Apigateway which has two api **OrderApi** and **ItemApi**. These api uses **Lambda authorizer** for athorization. React App gets the AWS jwt token on Login. This token is sent as a header to the ApiGateway which will be validated by the authorizer. I have another Apigateway with one api **userApi** which provides the information about the user. OrderApi and ItemApi call this api to get the user data. UserApi may or may not be directly called by any client. Now my question is

- what type of authentication and authorization is required for UserApi. Is it ok to pass the same Jwt token to the UserApi.
- Since UserApi is mostly called by other Api, is authentication required for it.
- Is this the right approach for common UserApi. I have other Api which will call to get User data.

Comment: yes, it is okay to pass the token along - wether or not you actually want that depends e.g. on wether or not a user is supposed to invoke it as well, or if it just an internal service. If it is an internal service you could rely solely on the IAM authentication authorizing the one lambda to invoke the second api.

Comment: It is most likely going to be used by other services like Order and Item services and few others. Are you referring such Api as internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It completely depends on your system. If user service is not accessible from outside and you have already authorize the user on 1st gateway then then there is no such need. So, you can avoid the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We have not decided to make the user service as fully internal. In some cases we might just call user service directly from the client also. In that case, does our current implementation make sense.

Comment: Now if user service is not accessible from outside directly, it is accessible from some gateway. then no need to send token to gateway. Gateway can validate the token and do authorization stuff. No need to send JWT token to user in such case as well.

Comment: Ideally services should never be directly exposed. It should be accessed through Gateway only.

Comment: When I said directly, I meant a React app can call gateway for UserApi instead of going through OrderApi.

Comment: yeah, so we no need to send token to user API service.

Comment: @user1592389 - Do you have any other doubt or query?

Comment: You said if useService Api is not accessible from outside no need of token. But if an api is not priviate api then it can be accessible from anywhere. Isn't that true. My userService Api is not private API so it needs token to validate.

Comment: We can say in such way - (1) User service is private, then don't need to pass user token. The token should be taken care at Gateway level itself. (2) User service is public, it means it is accessible from outside. Now there are 2 sub scenarios (a) User service is accessible from some trust worthy outside services only. In this case, we can make user service private and can setup some type of secure VPN tunnel to access user service, Or if we don't want to do this then we can use server to server authentication.

Comment: (b) User service is accessible by some Client (like Mobile or Web). Ideally we should avoid this. It should be accessible through Gateway only. So, better to make user service as private and go with solution of Sub scenario (a.).

Comment: xs2tarunkukreja - One last query. Does it make sense to have separate apigateway in front of userService. Can you also explain should we create only one apigateway for all the backend services. Are there cases when we have to create separate gateway

Comment: Ideally we should limit the number of API Gateways for our complete system. Better if we have one. Scenarios in which we can have multiple API Gateways:- (1) BFF Pattern - Here we have a separate gateway for web client and separate gateway for mobile. (2) One Gateway for all services in one bounded context. (3) Sometimes we have some services are deployed on private data centers, some on different clouds then we can have multiple gateways.